# sending an audio file via push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification

Is it possible to send an audio file as a push notification in android ? What i want to do is that the user can record his voice as a message and then that message should be delivered to all the users with that app as a push notification . is it possible ?

Comment: why don't you host the recoded file in your server and send the link instead isn't that better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to below document, CGM / C2DM / Push Notification can send only 4KB data, So, you can not send audio files via push notification,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html
"Apps can use "messages with payload" to deliver messages of up to 4 Kb"

But you can send http url of any audio file, in mobile app will receive audio file link via cgm message and download audio file using http connection.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do it, is use a module that has already implemented this for you. Technically you do the exact same thing that is described here, however with a single API call to providers like mBlox (http://developer.mblox.com), you'll be able to post your content and the devices you want to target, the hosting of the content, and the translation to a URL are being done for you, as well as sending the actual push notification.

Again, technically, it's the same as previous answers, however, for your personal integration it might be a quicker way to get to market.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Way, we can send a audio url in data from FCM. After that we can parse and sent to another activity.

In FIREBASE SERVICE

```
JSONObject object = null;
            try {
                String data = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
                Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
                object = new JSONObject(params);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("FCM err 1", e.getMessage());
            }

sendNotification(this, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(), object);
```

PUSH NOTIFICATION FUNCTION

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String Message, String Title, String ClickAction, JSONObject object) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final String CHANNEL_ID = "KRB";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {  // Build.VERSION_CODES.O
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "KRB_channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    // intent = Home
    Intent intent = new Intent(ClickAction);
    try {
        Log.e("FCMurl", object.getString("url"));
        Log.e("FCMtype", object.getString("type"));
        intent.putExtra("url", object.getString("url"));
        intent.putExtra("type", object.getString("type"));

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //   Toast.makeText(context,  e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("FCM err", e.getMessage());
    }


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_logo)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#531E6C"))  // small icon background color
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_sfach))
            .setContentTitle(Title)
            .setContentText(Message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

In activity

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String url;
    if(bundle != null){

        url = bundle.getString("url");
        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaplayer.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```